# Multiple owners for commerce order [or] Allow non-owner to pay for an commerce order

Tags: commerce

Scenario:

- Drupal site with "Member" and "Spouse" roles.
- For any given married couple, Member and Spouse each have their own user accounts.
- entity reference field from spouse defines the relationship between the 2 users
- an order exists, belonging to Member user (order->uid)

Desired functionality:

- Regardless of the uid value for order, allow either Member *or* Spouse to proceed through checkout and payment for the order.

**I realize this is not possible through vanilla [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).**  I'm looking for any ideas that will help me figure out how to implement this via existing Drupal techniques, or a custom module.

Specific questions:

- Has anyone achieved this successfully?
- Are the any specific ways (Drupal techniques) that could help solve this?
- What specific hooks or overrides should I be looking at?

Bonus points for elegant workarounds or shortcuts like a simple hook_access override, or a clever way to just-in-time reassign the order uid.

Comment: Please note my minor edits ... since asking "Is there a module for it?" is not allowed, according to the rules of this site (I did not invent them ...). Even though "There is a module for it!" is allowed as an answer ... Feel free to further rephrase, etc if needed ... Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, no i give up. Posted support request to Drupal issue queue.

Comment: Already? What's the link on D.O?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2685071

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade module for some ideas to see how it does the switching since it allows:

> "...(anyone with enough permissions) to switch users and surf the
>   site as that user (no password required). That person can switch back
>   to their own user account at any time."

You can then write a custom module.